# Law of sines not working in this case! WHY?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

We have the following triangle in which $BC=1000$, $AC=400$, angle $B$ is $45$ degrees, and angle $A$ is $\theta$.

I have to find the angle $\theta$, so I use sine law as follows:
$$\frac{1000}{sin(\theta)}=\frac{400}{sin(45)}$$
$$\therefore\ sin(\theta)=\frac{1000}{400\sqrt{2}}$$
$$\therefore\ sin(\theta)=\frac{5}{2\sqrt{2}}=1.767766953$$
Which is not possible! But where is the mistake?
[image]

Comment: Check the values. Currently you have typed in $AC + AB \lt BC$ which is not a triangle. Also based on your graph, it seems $AB$ and $AC$ are in the ratio $3: \sqrt{26}$

Comment: Thank you for this question, will try it with complex numbers as angles with other trigonometric identities 

Comment: Trig functions are only defined over real numbers. You can't use complex numbers as their arguments, @jimjim.

Comment: @HiterDean : looks like you haven't done the complex analysis course yet :), even if they were defined over real number, real numbers are complex numbers with their imaginary part set to 0, so yes, not only they are defined complex numbers, but they can be defined with matrix values as well.

Comment: @jimjim By coincidence I am currently studying Complex numbers!!! But by "real numbers" I meant purely complex numbers. Do you have any recommendations for books on complex numbers or combinatorics?  PS: Today I studied that we can take logs of complex numbers.

Comment: Any book that has the entire function theory should do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GReyes is right that your assumed side lengths do not make a triangle -- but that in itself does not explain your troubles, because your calculation doesn't even use the length of $AB$ anyway. *(Note: this value for $AB$ was later edited out of the question.)*

The real problem is that when $AC<BC$, then the angle at $B$ cannot be arbitrarily large. You need it to be small enough that a line from $B$ that makes the desired angle with $BC$ actually intersects a circle around $C$ with the specified radius $AC$. It's easy to see geometrically that $90^\circ$ will always be too large -- and here where $AC:BC = 4:10$, even $45^\circ$ is too large.

Answer (score 3):

Your triangle does not exist: $AC+AB<BC$! No surprise here.

Comment: OH! Thanks. Actually I did check for this, but I thought that theorem was $AC+AB\lt BC$!! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: The theorem says that the sum of any two sides is bigger than the third.

Comment: @Eric I know it; indeed everyone (I mean every human) knows it; shortest distance between any two points will be the straight line joining the two points, hence any other curve will be larger than the straight line. Isnt it intuitive? Of course I am talking about Euclidian plane.

Comment: This doesn't _actually_ explain the problem, though, since the OP's calculations make no use of his assumed value for AB, anyway.